# Flashed image of full debian to larger sd card. System still full

Tags: debian, memory, sd-card

I have debian running on a 16 GB sd card and it recently ran out of space (/dev/root is a 100%). I bought a 64 GB sd card and flashed my image of debian over to it. Even though it's running on the 64 GB sd card, it still says the memory is full. Is there a way I can show the OS that there is more space available? Or does it only know about the 16 GB?

Comment: What filesystem are you using on the card? You can [edit] your post.

Comment: What tool did you use to "flash" the OS onto the new disk? Have you tried [Clonezilla?](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone)

Comment: Did you extend the partition size and run `resize2fs` afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

I assumes that by "flashing" you meant do an exact copy od SD card, using another device (like windows, or another unix).

you increase physical space (16G to 64G), while leaving logical space (16G) untouched.

When copying you have to change underlaying strcuture :

- resize second partition on disk level size (`fdisk`),
- grow physical volume (`pvresize`),
- grow logical volume (`lvextend`),
- extend filesystems (`resize2fs`)

This might be done from local system (unsure about fdisk part).